# Postfix set EHLO name for virtual domains

Tags: postfix, email-server

I need to set EHLO name for my virtual domains. Postfix sending mail with EHLO as `JV.localdomain` where `JV` is my hostname my server ip is `62.210.xx.xx`

I am hosting 2 domains `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`

As I am getting blacklist by spamhose

How can I set EHLO name for virtual domains like If I send mail from `domain1.com` Postfix should EHLO `domain1.com` and If I send mail from `domain2.com` Postfix should EHLO `domain2.com` likewise

```
Dec 14 12:08:54 JV postfix/smtp[31513]: 0A08AB603DD: to=<somebody@yahoo.com>, relay=mta7.am0.yahoodns.net[66.196.118.36]:25, delay=0.58, delays=0.14/0.05/0.29/0.1, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host mta7.am0.yahoodns.net[66.196.118.36] said: 553 5.7.1 [BL21] Connections will not be accepted from 62.210.xx.xx, because the ip is in Spamhaus's list; see https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN5070.html (in reply to MAIL FROM command))

Dec 14 13:32:52 JV postfix/smtp[3732]: 50C1AB603DD: to=<somebody@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.167.27]:25, delay=0.37, delays=0.16/0.02/0.04/0.15, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1450096372 14si25083369wmq.78 - gsmtp)
```

I checked with spamhose, their it is mentioned as  62.210.xx.xx is listed in the XBL, because it appears in: CBL

**CBL**

```
IP Address 62.210.xx.xx is listed in the CBL. It shows signs of being infected with a spam sending trojan, malicious link or some other form of botnet.

It was last detected at 2015-12-15 12:00 GMT (+/- 30 minutes), approximately 2 hours, 30 minutes ago.
```

I have ClamAV antivirus in my linux, It does not show any malware.

```
This IP is infected (or NATting for a computer that is infected) with a spam-sending infection. In other words, it's participating in a botnet. If you simply remove the listing without ensuring that the infection is removed (or the NAT secured), it will probably relist again.
```

I try to do this following [this](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_helo_name) official document

**/etc/postfix/master.cf:**

```
mysmtp ... smtp -o smtp_helo_name=domain1.com
mysmtp ... smtp -o smtp_helo_name=domain1.com
```

**/etc/postfix/main.cf:**

```
smtp_helo_name = 62.210.xx.xx
```

But it did not worked.
Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting blacklisted because of the EHLO name you send, or perhaps due to some other (perhaps legitimate) reason?  You should set the EHLO name to whatever name your IP address resolves to; there's no requirement that it should be equal to the domainname of the sender.

Comment: @wurtel I checked with spamhose, their it is mentioned as  62.210.xx.xx is listed in the XBL, because it appears in: CBL

Comment: @wurtel `in CBL` IP Address 62.210.xx.xx is listed in the CBL. It shows signs of being infected with a spam sending trojan, malicious link or some other form of botnet.

It was last detected at 2015-12-15 12:00 GMT (+/- 30 minutes), approximately 2 hours, 30 minutes ago.

This IP is infected (or NATting for a computer that is infected) with a spam-sending infection. In other words, it's participating in a botnet. If you simply remove the listing without ensuring that the infection is removed (or the NAT secured), it will probably relist again.